# How do we get the new icon on the browser book-mark toolbar?

Tags: support

I have about a dozen sites book-marked on my browser's toolbar.  No matter what I try, I can't get the new icon to show up there.  It does show up in the search-engine menu.

What do I need to do to replace the little blue dialog bubble?

Edit: I performed all the suggestions from the answers.  I still get the blue dialog bubble.

Edit2: It finally appeared on my toolbar.

Comment: Visit [this link](http://cdn.sstatic.net/mathematica/img/favicon.ico) and do a hard refresh in your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the site from your bookmarks, and re-add it.

It worked for me in Firefox under OS X.

Answer (score 1):

As R.M suggested in a comment go to the [favicon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/mathematica/img/favicon.ico) and reload without using cache.
This is accomplished with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in most browsers.

Do the same for the [Meta favicon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/mathematicameta/img/favicon.ico) as needed.